# How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Using CSS, how can I apply more than one `transform`?

Example: In the following, only the translation is applied, not the rotation.

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: translate(-20px,0px);        
}
```

Answer (score 1382, accepted):

You have to put them on one line like this:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-20px,0px);
}
```

When you have multiple transform directives, only the last one will be applied. It's like any other CSS rule.

---

Keep in mind multiple transform one line directives are **[applied from right to left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Values)**.

This: `transform: scale(1,1.5) rotate(90deg);`
and: `transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1,1.5);`

will **not** produce the same result:

```css
.orderOne, .orderTwo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.orderOne {
  transform: scale(1, 1.5) rotate(90deg);
}

.orderTwo {
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="orderOne">
  A
</div>

<div class="orderTwo">
  A
</div>
```

Comment: I tried separating them by a "," like its done with multiple shadows, but that didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: is it possible to apply one tranformation before other...like skew before rotate. As for me no matter what i do, element is rotated first and then skewed which results in something that is not what i want.

Comment: so noway to split them into multiple lines

Comment: transform:translate(100px,100px) rotate(45deg) translate(100px,100px) rotate(45deg);  equals  transform:translate(200px,200px) rotate(90deg) ,the last one will add

Comment: You may need to include a prefix for the transform to work in all browsers. Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25110511/2065702) for more information

Comment: Keep in mind multiple transform one line directives are **executed from left to right** - 

this: `transform: scale(1,1.5) rotate(90deg);`
and : `transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1,1.5);`

will **not** produce the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/852hzq9w/

Comment: @jave.web, You meant **right to left**, correct? For `transform: scale(1,1.5) rotate(90deg);`, the rotate would happen before the scale.

Comment: Good note on the order of the transform items. That was throwing my element off. Using `scale` first made my `translateY` very small.

Answer (score 53):

I'm adding this answer not because it's likely to be helpful but just because it's true.

In addition to using the existing answers explaining how to make more than one translation by chaining them, you can also [construct the 4x4 matrix yourself](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#three-d-transform-functions)

I grabbed the following image from [some random site I found while googling](https://web.archive.org/web/20140616142747/http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/ArbitraryAxisRotation.html) which shows rotational matrices:

Rotation around x axis: [image: Rotation around x axis]
Rotation around y axis: [image: Rotation around y axis]
Rotation around z axis: [image: Rotation around z axis]

I couldn't find a good example of translation, so assuming I remember/understand it right, translation:

```
[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[x y z 1]
```

See more at the [Wikipedia article on transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) as well as [the Pragamatic CSS3 tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20140829071149/http://9elements.com/html5demos/matrix3d/) which explains it rather well. Another guide I found which explains arbitrary rotation matrices is [Egon Rath's notes on matrices](http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/basic-3d-math-matrices)

Matrix multiplication works between these 4x4 matrices of course, so to perform a rotation followed by a translation, you make the appropriate rotation matrix and multiply it by the translation matrix.

This can give you a bit more freedom to get it just right, and will also make it pretty much completely impossible for anyone to understand what it's doing, including you in five minutes.

But, you know, it works.

Edit: I just realized that I missed mentioning probably the most important and practical use of this, which is to incrementally create complex 3D transformations via JavaScript, where things will make a bit more sense.

Comment: The "random site" at mines.edu is unfortunately now a dead link.

Comment: As is the 9elements link :(

Comment: @matt thanks for that, I'llsee if I can come up with some better links later today.

Comment: @MattSach Ok, apparently "later today" for me means "six months later", but at least the 9elements link is fixed (someone else fixed the random sites link with Wayback, and I followed their lead.)

Comment: I also made [this](https://rawgit.com/alexanderdickson/Transformation-Matrix/master/index.html) to help you understand them.

Comment: this truly doesn't fit into this topic

Comment: @user151496 yeah you're largely right. The main SO answer part is that you can do it, the rest is just there to be helpful.

Comment: This may be important for those trying to animate transformations via `@keyframes`.  Chromium71 doesn't appear to be able to handle animating (rather than transitioning) multiple  transformations, but presumably could animate a single transformational matrix.

Comment: Implementation and demo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133977/how-to-calculate-svg-transform-matrix-from-rotate-translate-scale-values/50433377#50433377

Answer (score 40):

You can also apply multiple transforms using an extra layer of markup e.g.:

```
<h3 class="rotated-heading">
    <span class="scaled-up">Hey!</span>
</h3>
<style type="text/css">
.rotated-heading
{
    transform: rotate(10deg);
}

.scaled-up
{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
```

This can be really useful when animating elements with transforms using Javascript.

Comment: Your forgetting the `transform-style: preserve-3d`

Comment: It's not essential for nested 2d transforms - depends on the desired result. Transform-origin will most likely come in handy.

Answer (score 23):

You can apply more than one transform like this:

```
li:nth-of-type(2){
    transform : translate(-20px, 0px) rotate(15deg);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

<s>Some time in the future</s>, (now available, see updates below) we can write it like this:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    rotate: 15deg;
    translate:-20px 0px;        
}
```

This will become especially useful when applying individual classes on an element:

```
<div class="teaser important"></div>

.teaser{rotate:10deg;}
.important{scale:1.5 1.5;}
```

This syntax is defined in the in-progress [CSS Transforms Level 2 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms), but can't find anything about current browser support other then chrome canary. Hope some day i'll come back and update browser support here ;)

Found the info in [this article](https://danielcwilson.com/blog/2017/10/all-the-transform-ways/) which you might want to check out regarding workarounds for current browsers.

**UPDATE**: feature has landed in firefox 72

**UPDATE**: now available in chrome 104, edge 104, safari 14.1, see [https://web.dev/css-individual-transform-properties/#:~:text=support%20these%20properties.-,Browser%20support,-%3A](https://web.dev/css-individual-transform-properties/#:%7E:text=support%20these%20properties.-,Browser%20support,-%3A)

Comment: Debatable if safe to use now. Only if you want to exclude 2% of users globally (those using older safari versions). https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_rotate

Comment: beautiful beautiful beautiful

Answer (score 4):

**Lesson I`ve learnt.**

If you are using `style`'s React css, don't include semicolons, even in the end of it because it is included automatically and internally by React.

Just like:

```
style={                             
  transform: "rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1)",
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but turned out to be very relevant to me recently. I found 'transform: matrix(..)' more convenient to use.
So for the issue in question, the below example applies ~15deg rotation and translation of 20px to the right (for convenience) on the x-axis.

```css
.matrixTransform {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: matrix(0.965,0.258,-0.258,0.965,20,0);
    font-size: 30px;
}
.combinedTransform {
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(15deg) translateX(20px);
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class=matrixTransform>A</div>
<div class=combinedTransform>B</div>
```

From what I gather this particular transform uses initial 4 parameters to represent transformations e.g. scale, rotate. And seem to be in rows by columns order.
The remaining two are translations in the x and y axis respectively.
I found [Wolfram Alpha cheat sheet (calculator)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=bd71841fce4a834c804930bd48e7b6cf&title=Rotation%20Matrices%20Calculator%20MyAlevelMathsTutor&theme=red&i0=1&i1=1&i2=15&i3=degrees&i4=clockwise&i5=0&i6=0&podSelect=) very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just start from there that in **CSS**, if you repeat 2 values or more, always last one gets applied, unless using `!important` tag, but at the same time avoid using `!important` as much as you can, so in your case that's the problem, so the second transform **override** the first one in this case...

**So how you can do what you want then?...**

**Don't worry**, transform accepts multiple values at the same time... So this code below will work:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-20px, 0px); //multiple
}
```

If you like to play around with transform run the iframe from **MDN** below:

```html
<iframe src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/pages/css/transform.html" class="interactive  " width="100%" frameborder="0" height="250"></iframe>
```

Look at the link below for more info:

[<< CSS transform >>](https://cssreference.io/property/transform/)

Answer (score 1):

as simply as this:

```
li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-20px, 0px);        
}
```

as explained here:

https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css.html

Answer (score 0):

**Transform Rotate and Translate in single line css:-How?**

```css
div.className{
    transform : rotate(270deg) translate(-50%, 0);    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg) translate(-50%, -50%); 
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="className">
  <span style="font-size:50px">A</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```