# How to calculate SVG transform matrix from rotate/translate/scale values?

Tags: svg, coordinate-transformation

I have following details with me :

```
<g transform="translate(20, 50) scale(1, 1) rotate(-30 10 25)">
```

Need to change above line to:

```
<g transform="matrix(?,?,?,?,?,?)">
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

translate(tx, ty) can be written as the matrix:

```
1  0  tx
0  1  ty
0  0  1
```

scale(sx, sy) can be written as the matrix:

```
sx  0   0
0   sy  0
0   0   1
```

rotate(a) can be written as the matrix:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  0
sin(a)   cos(a)  0
0        0       1
```

rotate(a, cx, cy) is the combination of translation by (cx, cy), rotation of *a* degrees and translation back by (-cx, -cy) ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute)). Multiplying matrices of these transformations results in:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx
sin(a)   cos(a)  -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy
0        0        1
```

If you multiply the translate(tx, ty) matrix with the rotate(a, cx, cy) matrix, you get:

```
cos(a)  -sin(a)  -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx + tx
sin(a)   cos(a)  -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy + ty
0        0        1
```

Which corresponds to the SVG transform matrix:

`(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a), -cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx + tx, -cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy + ty)`.

In your case that is: `matrix(0.866, -0.5 0.5 0.866 8.84 58.35)`.

If you include the scale (sx, sy) transform, the matrix is:

`(sx × cos(a), sy × sin(a), -sx × sin(a), sy × cos(a), (-cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx) × sx + tx, (-cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy) × sy + ty)`

Note that this assumes you are doing the transformations in the order you wrote them.

Comment: can you please elaborate a, cx, cy, tx and ty? so that i can try it out.

Comment: In your example a=-30 (degrees), cx=10, cy=25, tx=20, ty=50 (sx=1, sy=1). In general the rotation is given as rotate(a, cx, cy) and the translation as translate(tx, ty).

Comment: Sorry but in the 'Rotate(a, cx, cy)' what does the dot represent in '-cx.cos(a)'? Coming from a JavaScript background I don't understand what it means to apply cos/sin to an object directly, without Math.cos().

Comment: @NickBudden I was using it as short-hand for multiplication, but I've switched to a multiplication symbol to be less ambiguous.

Comment: That is incredibly useful.  I haven't done a matrix calculation in many years. So cx and cy are offsets, not coordinates...?

Comment: Don't forget to do the translate back post rotate (like i did)

Comment: @reabow - re: `So cx and cy are offsets, not coordinates...?` cx and cy are the center coordinates around which the rotation is done.  It doesn't have to be inside the figure being rotated.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge does this mean when the skewX and skewY are applied we could have this?

`(sx × cos(a), sy × sin(a) x tan(skY), -sx × sin(a) x tan(skX), sy × cos(a), (-cx × cos(a) + cy × sin(a) + cx) × sx + tx, (-cx × sin(a) - cy × cos(a) + cy) × sy + ty)`

Comment: I just tested my above and it's really nasty. I could use a bit of help.

Comment: @thednp What are you trying to do? It will depend on the order that the skews are done. If you're trying to combine multiple transformations while keeping all the variable, it's going to get messy.

Comment: @PeterCollingridge yes, I decided to quit digging into this, regular transforms will do, `matrix` is still a problem too hard for me to handle.

Answer (score 13):

First get the g element using document.getElementById if it has an id attribute or some other appropriate method, then call [consolidate](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#__svg__SVGTransformList__consolidate) e.g.

```
var g = document.getElementById("<whatever the id is>");
g.transform.baseVal.consolidate();
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve this with Objective C/iOS. is there any general method to get the matrix?

Comment: Although Peters answer explains the theory, and how you manually calculate the matrix, I think Roberts answer should be the accepted one. 
el.transform.baseVal.consolidate() is what you should use. There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Manfred the OP couldn't use it as explained in his comment to my answer so why on earth would he accept it?

Comment: To be honest I didnt read his comment, but  OP didnt mention Objective C/iOS in the question. 
I faced the same problem as stated in OPs question and nearly took the accepted answer, although the native javascript function consolidate() was what I really needed.

Comment: @Manfred Them's the breaks ;-), Askers often don't clearly set the constraints they are operating under when they write their question. Happy my answer helped you though.

Comment: This does not seem to work if transform is set through the CSS style attribute, which is how Chrome does it these days

Answer (score 3):

Maybe helpful:

1. [Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kolosovsky/rkqfzttk/) of how to find actual coordinates of transformed points
2. An implementation of the accepted answer:

   ```
   function multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB) {
       let aNumRows = matrixA.length;
       let aNumCols = matrixA[0].length;
       let bNumRows = matrixB.length;
       let bNumCols = matrixB[0].length;
       let newMatrix = new Array(aNumRows);

       for (let r = 0; r < aNumRows; ++r) {
           newMatrix[r] = new Array(bNumCols);

           for (let c = 0; c < bNumCols; ++c) {
               newMatrix[r][c] = 0;

               for (let i = 0; i < aNumCols; ++i) {
                   newMatrix[r][c] += matrixA[r][i] * matrixB[i][c];
               }
           }
       }

       return newMatrix;
   }

   let translation = {
       x: 200,
       y: 50
   };
   let scaling = {
       x: 1.5,
       y: 1.5
   };
   let angleInDegrees = 25;
   let angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * (Math.PI / 180);
   let translationMatrix = [
       [1, 0, translation.x],
       [0, 1, translation.y],
       [0, 0, 1],
   ];
   let scalingMatrix = [
       [scaling.x, 0, 0],
       [0, scaling.y, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
   ];
   let rotationMatrix = [
       [Math.cos(angleInRadians), -Math.sin(angleInRadians), 0],
       [Math.sin(angleInRadians), Math.cos(angleInRadians), 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
   ];
   let transformMatrix = multiplyMatrices(multiplyMatrices(translationMatrix, scalingMatrix), rotationMatrix);

   console.log(`matrix(${transformMatrix[0][0]}, ${transformMatrix[1][0]}, ${transformMatrix[0][1]}, ${transformMatrix[1][1]}, ${transformMatrix[0][2]}, ${transformMatrix[1][2]})`);
   ```