# SVG transformations: skew to matrix

Tags: svg, matrix

using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133977/how-to-calculate-svg-transform-matrix-from-rotate-translate-scale-values), I was able to find how to get matrix transformations from the others except for the "skew" ones. Is there any posibility to make a matrix from "skewX" or "skewY" functions? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#SkewXDefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skew transformation means you shift the vertices along one coordinate, and the magnitude of this shift is given by the other coordinate.

This means the `skewX(a)` transformation is:

```
1 tan(a) 0
0   1    0
0   0    1
```

Analogically, `skewY(a)` is the transpose:

```
  1    0 0
tan(a) 1 0
  0    0 1
```

The neutral axis of the transformations (along which the transformation has no effect) is the axis that intersects the origin. To change this, chain it with translation transformations as described by the answer you linked.