# translateX and translateY on same element?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Is it possible to apply a CC translate X and Y on the same element?

If I try this the translateX is overridden by the translateY:

```
.something { 
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css3)

Comment: I understand this is a demo, but just rememeber to include browser prefixing as well

Comment: @Jeroen Not a duplicate, this is actually different.

Comment: @mattytommo Isn't it? Wouldn't `.something { transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); }` be a solution?

Comment: @Jeroen It would, but the real answer is the existence of the `translate` property which encompasses both axes, thus removing the need for duplicate properties.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Answer (score 15):

In your case, you can apply both X and Y translations with the `translate` property :

> `transform:  translate(tx[, ty])  /* one or two <translation-value> values */`

[[source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#translate)]

for your example, it would look like this :

```
.something { 
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

**DEMO:**

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

As stated by this answer [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css3) you can apply several transforms on the same element by specifying them on the same declaration :

```
.something { 
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can combine X and Y translates into a single expression:

```
transform: translate(10px, 20px); /* translate X by 10px, y by 20px */
```

And, in general, several transforms into a single rule:

```
transform: translateX(10px) translateY(20px) scale(1.5) rotate(45deg);
```