# Shift and Rotation Using CSS

Tags: html, css

i hope everyone is doing well today. 
I am new to HTML and CSS and I would appreciate your help, please.
I would like to shift and rotate an image (at the same time) when i hover the mouse over the image. However I have only been able to achieve either rotation, or shifting but not both. I would like to do this using CSS and here is the code.

In general, I am using Mozilla Firefox to test out most of my HTML and CSS code but I do understand for Google Chrome and IE I should use similar code like -webkit-transform and -ms-transform.

Thank you!

```
.data3 img:hover{
transform:rotate (70deg);
transform: translate3d(80px,0px,0px);
transition: transform .5s ease-out;/*want to rotate and shift slowly*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the tanslate and the rotate command behind each other:

```
transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50px);
```

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css3).

Comment: thank you very much, it works :)