# Css-transform doesn't apply if element use animation

Tags: css, animation, css-transforms

I have a problem with transform property. There is a box with `position: absolute`. To put this in the center of parent div I use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` because in real project I have adaptive page. So, I can't use px and negative margin.

In addition I want to apply zoomIn animation and see that with animation line `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` doesn't work. I suppose, it's because of double transform property.

How can I fix it?

This is example on Codepen https://codepen.io/pndparade/pen/VKGXPj

```
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.box-in{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, .1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css)

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZprjEm

Answer (score 0):

you can use calc by left and right position:

```
left:calc(50% - 100px);
top: calc(50% - 100px);
```

when you need older browser support you can add:

```
left:-webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
left:-moz-calc(100% - 100px);
left:calc(50% - 100px);

right:-webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
right:-moz-calc(100% - 100px);
right: calc(50% - 100px);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For `horizontally` center i have use `margin 0` tricks and vertical i have use scale.**

> Note: better understand i marked `.box` `green bg`

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
}
.box{
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}
.box-in{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:-webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  top:-moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  top:calc(50% - 100px);
  background: #fff;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, .1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-in"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how you want the final result, but the general solution for this would be to combine the transform properties together like below:

```
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, .1) translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%);
```

For example:

- To make the element zoom in and scale at the same time: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrkAZQ
- To make the element scale first before zooming in: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgZpKB

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set on the animation both transform.

Also tricky is the **order** of the transforms...

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.box{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
.box-in{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform:  translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  to {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, .1);
    transform:  translate(-50%, -50%) scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-in"></div>
</div>
```