# Is there a way to 'freeze' previous CSS transformations before applying more?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, rescale

In the snippet below I have a div that's rotated 45 degrees. How can we shrink this div along the X axis ***without modifying the HTML at all***?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #eee, #888 );
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border-width: 0.05rem;
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
  
  transform: rotate( 45deg );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

### Example achieved using a wrapper element

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  margin: auto;
  
  transform: scaleX( 0.75 );
}
div > div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #eee, #888 );
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border-width: 0.05rem;
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
  
  transform: rotate( 45deg );
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div></div>
  
</div>
```

How can we achieve the above without adding any markup to the original example consisting of only 1 div? Of course we can do all things with JavaScript but the interest here is specifically if this is possible with only CSS. Perhaps through pseudo elements?

**EDIT** To explain why this is not a duplicate of [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css) and simply placing the transforms on the same line a specific order does not work see the snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #eee, #888 );
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border-width: 0.05rem;
  border-color: #666;
  border-style: solid;
  
  transform: rotate( 45deg ) scaleX( 0.75 );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The transforms from before aren't 'remembered'. The scaling is done from a perspective as if the div was still in its original position before it was rotated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css)

Comment: Put them both on one line: `transform: scaleX(0.75) rotate( 45deg );`, the order is important.

Comment: Thank you @JasonGoemaat but this isn't a duplicate. I'm not asking how to apply more than one transform to an element. I'm asking how to keep the previous transformations before the other rules are applied.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat Please see my edit and the last Snippet I've provided.

Comment: Check the order. With `scaleX` first, it works as expected.

Comment: @Purag You're right. Didn't think that would work here. Thank you so much. Make a answer if you want and I'll accept.