# CSS3 Multiple Transforms: translate() and scale()

Tags: css, css-transitions

I found out how to apply multiple transforms with [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css) but I am wondering how I can control them a bit better.

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
            
#box:hover {
  transform: scale(2, 2) translate(25px, 25px);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Text</div>
```

The animation starts with the `scale()` before the `translate()` starts to kick in.  Strangely enough, I can't seem to swap the `translate()` and `scale()` around as it will scale but won't translate when I do it.

How do I alter this so that the top and left of the `div` does not move up and left?  I want both transforms to start together so you don't get the appearance of the `div` moving up and left to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I alter this so that the top and left of the div does not move up and left?

You stop moving it around in the first place … and specify where you want the origin of the transformation(s) to be instead:

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 25%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: top left; /* add this in */
}
            
#box:hover {
  transform: scale(2, 2); /* no translate here */
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Text</div>
```