# CSS - Image shifts away from center after rotation transformation

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am recreating the [Atom.io](http://www.atom.io) header where there is 10 spinning circles rotating at different speeds. I got most of it done except when I apply a `tranform` property to my circles, they shift away from atom image.

[image: What I have so far]
I suspect that it's my positioning that is wrong somewhere but after lots of trial and error I cannot find the problem.

Could anyone see a flaw in my code?

I've included a codepen 
[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKXxJp)

Comment: This is caused by you applying the `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` in your animation. This just overrides the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` that you were using to center your circles instead of adding to it.

Comment: you're totally right, I remember learning about that. How would I combine them in this case? the translate is on the parent and the rotation is on the child but the rotation is a full on animation?

Comment: The "cheaty" way would be to set the animation to just use `transform: rotate(Xdeg) translate(-50%, -50%);` or you could take a different route to centering the items, but that may be a bit difficult.

Comment: I've now explained an alternative route to centering the elements in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue in this case is that when the animation is applied to the element, it uses the `transform: rotate(Xdeg);` to rotate the element. This wouldn't be an issue had the centering not also been done using the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` property. This issue is [demonstrated in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css) as an example.

In order to fix this issue, we have to either:

1. Change the rotate in the animation to also include our `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`. This would end up being `translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(Xdeg);`
2. Change the way that centering is handled on the page.

Considering the first option is pretty straightforward, I'm just going to give an example of the second option. This example uses [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to center the items on the page. This is done using the strategy found [here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/).

```
.example-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I've also changed most of the classes and structure just for simplicity purposes and to demonstrate my solution.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #343233;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  /*font-size: 16px;*/
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.full-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 366px;
  height: 366px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper .logo {
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper .logo .wordmark,
.wrapper .logo .icon {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper .circles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: rotating;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation-duration: 31s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation-duration: 33s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation-duration: 33s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation-duration: 34s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(7) {
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(8) {
  animation-duration: 40s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(9) {
  animation-duration: 44s;
}

.wrapper .circles .circle:nth-child(10) {
  animation-duration: 46s;
}
```

```html
<section class="full-page flex-container">
  <div class="wrapper flex-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-atom-wordmark-65fad016a61e71c82c2cdd18d94e911f.svg" alt="logo" class="wordmark">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-logo-9fb707770c2c8a018b7a2933906c3436.svg" alt="atom" class="icon">
    </div>
    <div class="circles">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-red-semi-085b4e44d49b2ffe935cc1b2b3094ce8.svg" alt="c1" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-red-be5d1b8a52c13bf286560aba3e4c8c30.svg" alt="c2" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-orange-semi-d2010f0f8e41e03dbf2b5c52166abe4b.svg" alt="c3" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-orange-b3bddfb758b91d22f43d0e14ed8e29da.svg" alt="c4" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-yellow-semi-545681fe77ff01659d472bd379a9f38b.svg" alt="c5" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-yellow-ff207a58ad4f450ea9ac0e17224b39f1.svg" alt="c6" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-green-semi-2d5bc571ee90e710d93f7ae7ddd06e85.svg" alt="c7" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-green-6ab85a1e7343a232273868031b242806.svg" alt="c8" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-blue-semi-7333f1323549be50644411b691b173dd.svg" alt="c9" class="circle">
      <img src="https://github-atom-io-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/assets/index-portal-blue-92fc2c151190795bd0147c03d4fb8352.svg" alt="c10" class="circle">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```