# Zoom hover with image CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to zoom a picture with Transform->scale. However when i hover on the picture, the hover don't work.

For Example: https://www.loberon.de/Wohnen/Sessel/Sessel-Bartley.html

I set CSS:

```
#zoomTrigger{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

The picture is enlarged but the hover don't work.

I tried with

```
#zoomTrigger:hover{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

But still don't work :(

Here is orginal when i hover:

[image]

After i made Scale(1.2). You can see a white space when i zoom:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code snippet here to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Well, the scale of the non-hovered image and of the hovered image are the same, maybe you should set the first to 1, and it would solve the problem. However, if you are looking for a zoom effect only around the cursor, then you'll have to use JS.

Comment: I have updated this post for understand, what i mean :)

Comment: show us code you have tried, dont post images..!!!

Comment: i have made only CSS-Code for the image in this link.

Comment: The Code i have showed up there.

Comment: @VoiMập  YOu should use any js library for it.

Comment: I have no idea, how i can with js for this >.<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.fond{position:absolute;padding-top:85px;top:0;left:0; right:0;bottom:0;
 background-color:#00506b;}

.style_prevu_kit
{
    display:inline-block;
    border:0;
    width:196px;
    height:210px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1); 
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);   

}
.style_prevu_kit:hover
{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);   
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div align="center" class="fond">
<div style="width:1000px;">

<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#cb2025;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#f8b334;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#97bf0d;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#00a096;"></div>
<div class="style_prevu_kit" style="background-color:#93a6a8;"></div>


<div style=" padding:5px; color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:30px; font-family:'Roboto';padding-top:20px;">CSS <font style="font-weight:400;">HOVER</font></div>
        <a href="http://www.wifeo.com/code" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><div style="  color:#b5e6e3; font-weight:300; font-size:20px; font-family:'Roboto';">www.wifeo.com/code</div></a>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean this?

Comment: Thank for your reply.I have already updated my post. You can see to understand, what i mean:)