# What does position-bottom mean in devtools?

Tags: html, css, css-position, velocity.js

[image: screenshot of devtools]

I'm experimenting with some transforms and animations using Velocity.js. One of the animations scales an element that's been absolutely positioned, but for some reason, I can't get the element to center.

According to Firefox Developer Edition's devtools, there's a negative `position-bottom` and `position-right` on the element, but I can't figure out where it's coming from. It's parent is static positioned and it's just a regular div with `height: 100%`.

Where could these be coming from?

Computed styles for div in question (while it's being scaled):

```
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
border-top-left-radius: 50%;
border-top-right-radius: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(9, 29, 35);
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 2139.52px;
left: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
transform: matrix(0.00870397, 0, 0, 0.00870397, 0, 0);
width: 2139.52px;
```

and computed styles for parent div:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(9, 29, 35);
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 944px;
overflow: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
width: 1920px;
```

[Here's a jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/rufamabagi) for reference. The big black square should be centered, but it's not for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question's title :**

`position-bottom` denotes the distance in pixels between the current element and its immediately positioned parent (in this case the ***body tag*** [becomes the parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) as no previous parent of the black-box is positioned i.e. *all are positioned static [by default]*).

***Why the negative value though? shouldn't the distance be positive? given the dimensions of the black box is less than that of the parent?***

It should be normally, but you have created a box that is bigger than the parent element and have scaled it down using transform properties. So when left = 0 and top = 0, the super big unscaled child is being positioned, not the scaled down version.

***I will explain the math of the negative bottom position:***

```
bottom-position = parentHeight - childOriginalHeight 
right-position = parentWidth - childOriginalWidth
```

**Solution :**

1. Position your parent element (position: relative / absolute)
   [refer relative vs absolute: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/]
2. Now use this CSS to center your black box

```css
{
  ...    
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scaleX() scaleY();
  ...
}
```

**Note:**

1. (***top = 50%*** and ***left = 50%*** css properties, position the child's boundaries ***(50% of the parent's dimensions from the top and left)*** with respect to the parent's boundaries, where as ***transform - translate*** moves the element, ***(-50% of that element's dimensions to the top and left)*** from that element's center). **refer:** https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/
2. Keep in mind multiple transform one line directives are [applied from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765771/4540673)
3. So scale down your element (*remember that transforms in the right get applied first*) and then translate it (*which is what you are trying to do*).
   .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css below to the div:

```css
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
width: auto;
margin:0 auto;
```