# Applying css scale afer rotate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I always assumed that CSS transform operations would occur in order, so I was a bit surprised seeing that `transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(2)` is displaying a rotated rectangle and not a rhombus.

It works when applying the scale to the parent element. However my question is:
How can I transform a

Example (how it is not working): https://jsfiddle.net/avpqjL0y/1/

[image]

Comment: What do you think what `rotate(45deg) scaleX(2)` would do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply swipe the order of the values in the transform property:

```
transform: scaleX(2) rotate(45deg)
```

transform gets executed from right to left. See: [How to apply multiple transforms in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css)

You can also use @keyframes to achieve this effect. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Answer (score 0):

**You can use scale and rotate in this order, to get your result.**

```css
#main {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
  height:100vh;
}
#inner {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: #f00;
  transform:scaleX(.8) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not exactly the form I wanted. See my updated question above. However I just got the order of execution for transform wrong.

Comment: @LucaAdrian I hope, This make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You must using scale instate of scaleX  ;)

```
div {
//...
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(2) 

    }
```

Comment: I thought the OP wanted to scale the height though, not the whole object.

Comment: Yes correct I wanted to scale one size my issue was that I misunderstood the execution order of transform operations...