# Increase Image Size on Hover

Tags: css, hover

I need help increasing svg image size on hover at countrymusicfy.com

I tried different variations on the CSS below:

```
img:hover {
    transform: scale (1.5);
}
```

Comment: also tried .svg-icon img:hover { transform: scale (1.5); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the space between the scale(1.5)
so code should look like:

```
  img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Any suggestions on changing the scale for different classes? For instance, .svg-icon img:hover { transform: scale(1.5); } does not work

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765755/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-css] hope this helps